# INSERT statement just not working! (PHP+MYSQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with INSERT SQL sentence. It just do nothing! (and not showing any error).
When I am printing $qry, it looks just fine.
what can be the problem?
This is the code:

```
<?php 
include('conn.php');
$result=mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci",$mysql_link);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where userID=".$_SESSION['IDENT'],$mysql_link);
if (!$result)
{

    echo "ERROR: error occured in MySQL query.";

}
else 
{

    if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1)
    {

    //This will be shown only to registered users.
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            if (($row['userRank']==100)||($row['userRank']==10))
                {
                    $qry="INSERT INTO users (NickName, username, userpass, userEmail, userRank, userOOlamR, userPhone, userPhone2, userStr, userCity, userMikud, userOOlamID) VALUES ('" . $_POST['nname'] . "', '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . md5($_POST['userpass']) . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', 2, 1, '" . $_POST['cellphone1'] . "', '" . $_POST['cellphone2'] . "', '" . $_POST['street'] . "', '" . $_POST['city'] . "', " . $_POST['mikud'] . ", " . $_POST['oolam'] . ")";
                    $res=mysql_query($qry ,$mysql_link);
                    ?><div align="center">
                    <table width="50%" height="20%" style="Border-Style:dotted;Border-Width:1px;Border-Color:a01220;background-color: rgba(190, 200, 230, 0.5);">
                    <td><div align="Center"><font face="Arial" size="2" color="Black"> SUCCESS!<br></div></td>
                    </table>
                    </div><div align="left">
                    <?php
                    echo $qry; ?>
                    </div><?php
                }
            Else
                {
                    //SECURITY
                }



        }
    }
}
include('cconn.php');
?>
```

The problem was I had another field in the table that I didn't treat in my INSERT statement at all.

Comment: Your indentation style is horrible. Put your curly brackets on the same indentation level as the control statement they belong to. Besides that, your large if..else blocks can be optimized and you need to fix the SQL injection issues in your code. And you might want to consider not using HTML elements that are deprecated for years now (`<font>`).

Comment: As for the identation style, sorry I'm a newbie to PHP. I just whant it to work and then continue with sql injections issues... it just adding nothing to the DB...

Comment: Are you sure your input isn't terminating the query? You'll likely be lectured on security for blindly accepting session and post data in your query. look into mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @Tzahi: I don't understand what you expect to happen in this code that is not happening. You mentioned "update SQL" but I don't see any updates. Is it failing to insert a record into the users table? Did I understand correctly that it is echoing out the insert statement to the screen, or is it not getting to that point in the code?

Comment: where is the update statement

Comment: You can see that I wrote echo $qry in my code for checking if the input is ok, IT IS! And as I said: after It'll work and update the DB I'll add input validations. Please focus the main question, Why isn't the DB being update by this sentence?

Comment: @rla: It's echoing the insert statement and it looks just fine. SORRY I'M MISTAKING- THE INSERT STATEMENT (not update...)

Comment: What is the return value of `mysql_query`?  Are there any errors in the logs?  If you take the raw query and manually execute it against the database, what is the result?

Comment: There are no errors in the logs. How can I know the return value of mysql_query?(I'm a newbie..) also didn't understand at your last question what should I try to do

Comment: @Tzahi: Check out the first example in the documentation for mysql_query.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php  Do what that example does, checking the value of your $res variable and if it evaluates to false, print the value of mysql_error()

Comment: @rla Thanks alot!- just done it and so the silly mistake! it was a problem with one of table column which didn't get default value and I didn't want to insert any data in it... so the mistake was: Invalid query: Field 'userLLTimeStamp' doesn't have a default value. now it works!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your query the mistake lines here..

$qry="INSERT INTO users (NickName, username, userpass, userEmail, userRank, userOOlamR, userPhone, userPhone2, userStr, userCity, userMikud, userOOlamID) VALUES ('" . $_POST['nname'] . "', '" . $_POST['username'] . "', '" . md5($_POST['userpass']) . "', '" . $_POST['email'] . "', 2, 1, '" . $_POST['cellphone1'] . "', '" . $_POST['cellphone2'] . "', '" . $_POST['street'] . "', '" . $_POST['city'] . "', **" . $_POST['mikud'] . ", " . $_POST['oolam'] . ")";**

use this

```
  $nickname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nname']);
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $userpass=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userpass']));
    $useremail=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $userrank=2;
    $useroolamR=1;
    $userphone=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cellphone1']);
    $userphone2=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cellphone2']);
    $userstr=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['street']);
    $usercity=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $usermikud=$_POST['mikud'];
    $useroolamid=$_POST['oolam'];

    $qry="INSERT INTO users (NickName, username, userpass, userEmail, userRank, userOOlamR, userPhone, userPhone2, userStr, userCity, userMikud, userOOlamID) VALUES ('$nickname','$username','$userpass','$useremail', $userrank, $useroolamR,'$userphone','$userphone2','$userstr','$usercity',$usermikud,$useroolamid)";
```

Comment: Well, thank you for your answer, it is more arranged this way, but still it isn't working, and echoing it OK, just as it was before...

Comment: That wasn't a mistake because "userMikud" and "userOOlamID" are setted to be an int in the MySQL DB.

Comment: now it says: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' [on the line $qry="INSERT INTO users...]

Comment: if you can let us know the table structure so it will be easy to solve the issue

Comment: OOPS, I've pasted it without the "$" sign so that was why the error appeared. now I fixed it and it still the same... :(

Comment: userID- int A_I::NickName- text::username- text:: userpass- text:: userEmail-text::userRank-int::userOOlamR-int::userPhone-text::userPhone2-text::userStr-text::userCity-text::userMikud-int::userOOlamID-int::   [That's all...]

Comment: just update your question with the new answer.. it seems to be the error is not in the query

Comment: @Ampere Don't you think your example should demonstrate protection from sql injection?

Comment: I feel compelled to mention that both the question and the answer are suspect to a SQL Injection attack.  Give this question a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: -1 example does not demonstrate protection from sql injection